I am the last living human being on Earth. Does "humanity" remain an Essential Universal or become something else entirely?
In regard to Aristotle's Categories: Chapter 2-
If I die, I take the concept of humanity with me, because "humanity" has no other vessel to inhabit. While I am still human, just like Socrates was human, I am now the only entity in existence with that quality, unlike Socrates. Would this then make "humanity" an Accidental Particular? How does this fit into Aristotle's philosophy?

After the last man death, humanity will be an un-instantiated concept. The issue is: according to A, what sort of reality universals have if not instantiated?

+1 @MauroALLEGRANZA great response and great understanding!

@Howwhye you are welcome!

When it comes to categories, Aristotle was an essentialist. That means, he thought the essence of human beings was something that had an existence by itself. He saw it, like his master Plato, as an ideal human being, possessing all the virtues of a human. The model every human should strive to become by realising said virtues.
This idea does not depend on actual, living human beings. Being an ideal, a goal for everyone to strive for, it is obviously not an average or median version of all humans. In Aristotle's view, what humanity is actually or currently has nothing to do with what humanity should tend to be.
What you are describing, redefining the category "human" based on the only existing human, you, is called nominalism. It's the idea that categories don't exist by themselves, they're just a name we slap on a bunch of individual entities who share similarities, for convenience.
Under this view, it makes sense to redefine the concept of "human" as something sharing all your properties, since you are the only human there is,after all. It could also be seen as non sense, since you would be the only entity of this category so we could as well call it by your name.
Another way we can consider it, is that Aristotle defined human virtues to be the qualities of this ideal human (courage, wisdom, temperance, etc), that actual humans, necessarily imperfect, should strive to put in action. But if we changed the definition of "human" to match you, it would make the concept of virtue completely void: you are already you, there is no goal that you should strive for, no way you can improve yourself. You can't look up to yourself.
On the other hand if the ideal human model is still the same, you can still improve yourself and try to be that guy.

I follow what you are saying. However, was Aristotle an essentialist in regard to other things, like beds and dogs? Did Aristotle believe in the "ideal" dog? Dogness" would fit under the Essential Universal category, unless I am mistaken. So to reframe my question a little, my dog is the last dog on earth. Does "dogness" remain a Universal Essential? If dogs don't exist, it means nothing to be a dog, just like it means nothing to be a unicorn.

@KeltonSmith yes, AFAIK Aristotle thought there is an ideal dog, an ideal frog, an ideal broom...

Ok thank you for expanding
